# XSLT looping XML file, removing children, reformat date

Tags: xslt, loops

I have a large XML file and I'm trying to write XSLT which loops through the entire node set (PRESOL, COMBINE and FAIROPS) and deletes all children nodes named DATE.  Then, I want to reformat the parent node's DATE to mm/dd/yyyy.  Here is my code, I'm using version 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="DATE">
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 2), '/', substring(., 3, 2), '/', substring(., 5, 4))"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DATE[preceding::DATE]"/>
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to loop through an entire node set.  I'm hoping not to hard code the parent node names.  Currently, my code only processes the first parent node.  Also, if a parent node has no children, my code is deleting its DATE node and I don't understand why.  Any help would is greatly appreciated.

My input

```
 <NOTICES>
  <PRESOL>
   <DATE>01242013</DATE>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
   <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
   <CHANGES>
    <MOD>
     <DATE>01242013</DATE>
     <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
     <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
     <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
     <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
    </MOD>
   </CHANGES>
  </PRESOL>
  <COMBINE>
    <DATE>02102013</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Air Force Materiel Command]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[Tinker OC-ALC  -  (Central Contracting)]]></LOCATION>
    <ZIP>73145-3015</ZIP>
  </COMBINE>
  <COMBINE>
   <DATE>02092013</DATE>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Military Sealift Command]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[MSC Norfolk]]></LOCATION>
  </COMBINE>
  <COMBINE>
   <DATE>02092013</DATE>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Grand Junction VAMC)]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[Veterans Affairs Medical Center]]></LOCATION>
  </COMBINE>
  <PRESOL>
   <DATE>12272012</DATE>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
   <CHANGES>
    <MOD>
     <DATE>01112013</DATE>
     <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
     <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
     <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
    </MOD>
   <MOD>
    <DATE>01112013</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
   </MOD>
   <MOD>
    <DATE>01142013</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
   </MOD>
   <MOD>
    <DATE>01142013</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
   </MOD>
  </CHANGES>
 </PRESOL>
 <FAIROPP>
  <DATE>02082013</DATE>
  <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
  <OFFICE><![CDATA[Bureau of Medicine and Surgery]]></OFFICE>
  <LOCATION><![CDATA[NH Camp Pendleton]]></LOCATION>
  <ZIP>92055</ZIP>
  <CHANGES>
   <MOD>
    <DATE>02122011</DATE>
    <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
    <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
    <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
   </MOD>
  </CHANGES>
 </FAIROPP>
</NOTICES>
```

Desired output:

```
<NOTICES>
<PRESOL>
 <DATE>01/24/2013</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
 <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
 <CHANGES>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
   <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
  </MOD>
 </CHANGES>
</PRESOL>
<COMBINE>
 <DATE>02/10/2013</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Air Force Materiel Command]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[Tinker OC-ALC  -  (Central Contracting)]]></LOCATION>
 <ZIP>73145-3015</ZIP>
</COMBINE>
<COMBINE>
 <DATE>02/09/2013</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Military Sealift Command]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[MSC Norfolk]]></LOCATION>
</COMBINE>
<COMBINE>
 <DATE>02/09/2013</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Grand Junction VAMC)]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[Veterans Affairs Medical Center]]></LOCATION>
</COMBINE>
<PRESOL>
 <DATE>12/27/2012</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
 <CHANGES>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
  </MOD>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
  </MOD>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
  </MOD>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
  </MOD>
 </CHANGES>
</PRESOL>
<FAIROPP>
 <DATE>02/08/2013</DATE>
 <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
 <OFFICE><![CDATA[Bureau of Medicine and Surgery]]></OFFICE>
 <LOCATION><![CDATA[NH Camp Pendleton]]></LOCATION>
 <ZIP>92055</ZIP>
 <CHANGES>
  <MOD>
   <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
   <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
   <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
  </MOD>
 </CHANGES>
</FAIROPP>
</NOTICES>
```

Comment: I think you mean `DATE[../ancestor::*/DATE]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATE[preceding::DATE]` is incorrect because the `preceding` axis includes nodes which are *not* ancestors of the current node. So this will match *all* DATEs other than the first one in the entire document. What you want to say is "any parent of the current DATE element also has a DATE element":

```
<xsl:template match="DATE[../ancestor::*/DATE]"/>
```

The `..` is to make sure we don't match the context node (the current `DATE` element that is seeing if any of its ancestors have a DATE element).

BTW, your method of creating a new element is terrible. Use this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="DATE">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 2), '/', substring(., 3, 2), '/', substring(., 5, 4))"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Although in your case it's not even necessary--just have the template match the text node directly:

```
<xsl:template match="DATE/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 2), '/', substring(., 3, 2), '/', substring(., 5, 4))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Final version of your template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATE/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 2), '/', substring(., 3, 2), '/', substring(., 5, 4))"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATE[../ancestor::*/DATE]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you for the suggestions and taking the time to explain.